# Twitter premium search query tweets in english

Tags: tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am looking through tweepy as well as twitterAPI to filter past twitter data. In order to filter past data you require either the full_archive_search or 30_days search methods. Unfortunately unlike the standard search there isnt a way to stream only tweets in English (i.e the standard search has an option called lang which can be set to 'en' to stream only tweets in English.) I am just wondering if there is a similar feature for the premium search or any other method?

By the way I am using premium search using a sandbox version (free but limited streaming options)

These are my tweepy and twitterAPI streaming methods

```
def stream_past_tweets(self,keyword,search_from,search_to):
    """ Method to search for past tweets using Tweepy """

    # Stream past twitter data (since 2006)
    pastTweetsObj = self.api.search_full_archive(
        environment_name = 'VolcanicDisaster',
        query = keyword,
        fromDate = search_from,
        toDate = search_to
    )

def stream_past_tweets(self,keyword,search_from,search_to,num_tweets):
    """ Method to stream past tweets using TwitterAPI"""

    # Make request to twitter API
    self.req = self.api.request(
        'tweets/search/%s/:%s' % ('fullarchive','VolcanicDisaster'),
        #'tweets/search/fullarchive/:VolcanicDisaster',
        {
            'query': keyword,
            'fromDate' : search_from,
            'toDate' : search_to,
            'maxResults' : num_tweets,
        }
    )
```

Any ideas on which parameter can be included to stream tweets in English?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the Premium documentation on supported search operators:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators

There is a `lang` operator which you can include in your `query` like this:

```
'query': keyword + ' lang:EN'
```